# [JSOUP]Is it impossible to get multi page data while the page switching function is using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsoup

As my title, is it possible to get more the one page data if the page switching function in the targeted website is using javascript instead of `xxx.aspx?page=2` ?

I believe the targeted website is switching like this

```
<select name="Centlist1$cmb_page"     
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'Centlist1$cmb_page\',\'\')', 0)" 
id="Centlist1_cmb_page" class="dropdown"> 
<option selected value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option> 
<option value="3">3</option> 
<option value="4">4</option> 
<option value="5">5</option> 
</select>
```

And the javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var theForm = document.forms['form1'];

if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.form1;

}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}

//]]>

</script>
```

Comment: You could use ScriptEngine or discard jsoup for getting the data and using selenium web driver. After that you can still use jsoup for parsing.

Comment: Or attempt to find out how the link is constructed by the script, and use a regex to process that.